# Channel Form return to new window

Tags: channel-form

I would like a channel form return path to open in a new window upon submission. Is there any way to do this?  Below is the template code I have:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="projects" entry_id="{last_segment}" limit="1"}
                        <h2>{title}</h2>
                        <ul class="buttons">
                            {project_proof orderby="row_id" sort="desc" limit="1"}
                                <li>
                                    {exp:channel:form
                                        channel="projects"
                                        entry_id="{last_segment}"
                                        return="images/uploads/proofs/{proof_file:filename}.{proof_file:extension}"
                                        orderby="row_id"
                                        sort="desc"
                                        limit="1"
                                        target="_blank"
                                    }
                                    <input type="hidden" name="field_id_77[row_order][]" value="row_id_{row_id}" />
                                    <input type="hidden" name="field_id_77[row_id_{row_id}][col_id_19]" value="{current_time format='%F %d, %Y - %g:%i:%s'}" />
                                    <input type="hidden" name="field_id_77[row_id_{row_id}][col_id_15]" value="{proof_date}" />
                                    <input type="hidden" name="field_id_77[row_id_{row_id}][col_id_18]" value="{proof_notes}" />
                                    <button class="button" type="submit">View details</button>
                                    {/exp:channel:form}
                                </li>

                                <li><a class="button" id="submitChanges">Submit changes</button></a></li>
                            {/project_proof}
                        {/exp:channel:entries}
```

Basically it returns an image so I want to have that image either open in a new window or download.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is a job for JavaScript. Here's a thread over at the main Stack Exchange questions forum which may be useful:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825078/jquery-post-response-in-new-window

Comment: I am not sure this will work. I am editing my post with the data I have on the site.  There are multiple forms on this template, but I could just not know what I am doing.